# Fetching offset from kafka high-level consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to fetch kafka message offset from high-level consumer in java program. Since I am using custom commitoffset property, i want to test whether my custom commitoffset is working fine or not. Can anyone help me how to get offset???
 i have come across with couple of kafka tools (like getoffsetshell) but it's not helpful in my testing.

Comment: Do you want to get the offset from each message after it is sent to Kafka? Like a callback method with the related Kafka metadata information?

Answer (score 0):

When getting a message from the `ConsumerIterator` you can also get the offset by doing the following:

```
    ConsumerConnector consumerConnector = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(getConsumerConfig());
    KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream = getKafkaStream(consumerConnector);
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> iterator = stream.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
        MessageAndMetadata<byte[], byte[]> messageAndMetadata = iterator.next();
        String message = new String(messageAndMetadata.message());
        long offset = messageAndMetadata.offset();
    }
```